# Ordering problem from combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

So the question is as follows.
**We will have an ordered parade of the flags of 15 countries through a street. In how
many ways can we order the flags in the parade if the flags of country X and Y cannot be next to each other.**

I know this is a problem from ordered selection without repetiton but I cannot see how to tackle this problem.
Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Can you count the number of permutations in which $X,Y$ *are* next to each other?

Comment: that would be 12! since two places are taken from X and Y ??

Comment: 13! * i meant sorry

Comment: Why $12!$  ?   Keep in mind that you might have $XY$ or $YX$.  First count those with $XY$.

Comment: $13!$ is still wrong.    Let's say you had $F_1, \cdots, F_{13}, X,Y$ as the fifteen flags.  If you combine $XY$ as a block that leaves you with $14$ things to arrange.

Comment: but we have 13 flags left.. how can we arrange 14 things.. i dont understand

Comment: You still need to place the $XY$ block somewhere.

Comment: Perhaps you are confused because $13$, or $15$, are too big to write out all the cases.  So, say you only had $3$ flags, $A, X,Y$.  Now how many ways can you arrange them so that $XY$ appears as a block?

Answer (score 2):

We can count the number of combinations taking into account all the possible sequences and removing those containing $XY$ and $YX$.

- Total combinations: $15!$
- Combinations with $XY$: this block can be placed in $14$ different spots (depending on where $X$ lies), and the rest of the
  flags can be ordered in $13!$ ways, so $14*13! = 14!$. Similarly you can think to $XY$ as a single letter and so you can order the $14$ letters in $14!$ ways.
- Combinations with $YX$: same as before, $14!$

So the possible combinations are $15!-2*14! = 14!*13$.

**Different Solution**

This nice result made me think to a different approach:
you can remove $Y$ and shuffle the remaining $14$ flags in $14!$ ways.
Now, where can you put $Y$ back in? You have $15$ spots but you can't place it next to $X$, so you need to remove 2 spots, so only $13$ are viable: $14!*13$.